# Marquee not working fine in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed an application which i used a marquee text which worked in android 2.3.6 and 4.0.1 but in android 4.1.1 it shows dots at the end . and marquee stops when focus changes. my code follows. thanks in advance .
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/bodybg"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/bodybg"
    >  
    <TextView       
      android:id="@+id/MarqueeText" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:scrollbars="horizontal"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"  android:paddingLeft="15dip" android:paddingRight="15dip" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
      android:background="@color/scroll_text"
      android:paddingTop="8dp"
      android:paddingBottom="8dp"
      ></TextView>
    <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/zigzag" 
                />
    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"


    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
   <TextView
       android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/home_body_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_title"
        android:textSize="32dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/theme" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/home_body_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_sub_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
     </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:weightSum="7"
      >  
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_weight="2">
     <TextView
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/tax_table_home"
        android:id="@+id/tax_calc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tax_table_home_screen_message"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navigator_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"

        />
     <TextView
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/tax_calc_home"
        android:id="@+id/tax_table"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tax_calc_home_screen_message"
        android:background="@drawable/navigator_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        />
     <TextView
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/tax_calender_home"
        android:id="@+id/calender"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calender_home_screen_message"
        android:background="@drawable/navigator_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        />

     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
     <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/theme" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout> 
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/navigator_bg"
    />
     </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`